# DataTable Select Extension / Navigation with keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, datatable

I am using Datatable and i have implemented the Select() extension on in, and i want to implement a function that allow the user to navigate on the table with keyup and keydown, but i don't know how can i do that.
I tried this, but only remove work:

```
 $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
            var tr = $(this);
            if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
               $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }        
          //on keypress within tr
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {
            var tabla = document.getElementById("example");
            var fila = tabla.getElementsByClassName('odd selected');
            var fila2 = tabla.getElementsByClassName('even selected');
            if (e.keyCode == 40){ //arrow down
                tr.next().addClass('selected');
                table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 38){ //arrow up
                tr.prev().addClass('selected');
                table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                }
            })
      } );
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT: this is my HTML

```
<button id="addRow">Insertar fila</button>
<button id="saveData">Guardar datos</button>
<div id="dynamic">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" width="100%" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="10%">NIF/NIE</th>
                <th width="10%">1er Apellido</th>
                <th width="10%">2do Apellido</th>
                <th width="10%">Nombre</th>
                <th width="10%">Sexo</th>
                <th width="10%">Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                <th width="10%">Fecha Contrato</th>
                <th width="10%">Demandante empleo larga duración</th>
                <th width="10%">Tipo Contrato</th>
                <th width="10%">% Jornada</th>
                <th width="10%">Discap.</th>
                <th width="10%">Causas Archivo. (1)</th>
                <th width="10%">Aut. SCSP</th>
                <th width="10%">Imp.Solic.</th>
                <th width="10%">Sust.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am adding data using ajax

Comment: share your HTML also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED! This is my code now:
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

```
  var tr = $(this);
  if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {

      $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
  else {
      table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
  }

//on keypress within tr
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {


      if (e.keyCode == 40){ //arrow down

          table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
          tr.next().addClass('selected');
          tr = table.$('tr.selected'); //This was what i needed

      }
      if (e.keyCode == 38){ //arrow up
           table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
          tr.prev().addClass('selected');
          tr = table.$('tr.selected'); // again here

      }
  })
```

I know this is not the best code but at least it work :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the lines to remove and add `selected` class should be in opposite order, here is what needs to be changed in your code

```
 if (e.keyCode == 40){ //arrow down

       // original lines
       //tr.next().addClass('selected');
       //table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');

       // new lines, with order changed
       table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
       tr.next().addClass('selected');

  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38){ //arrow up

       // same here switch the lines
       table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
       tr.prev().addClass('selected');

   }
```

Comment: Oh! nice! that work, but only work with the just above and below row... do you know why?

Comment: Why have you put your document keydown function inside tbody click function? It should be outside

Comment: Because i don't know how to take the row... if i put the keydown function, how can i take the row? How u can see in my code, i did in this way <code> var tr = $(this);</code>

Comment: I posted a solution :)